# Trouble implementing setAdatpter

Tags: android, adapter

I want to implement my own `ListView` but I have some problems. I have the following code:

```
private ArrayList<ItemChat> itemsChat;
private ListView lv;
......

public void show (View v){
     lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
     itemsChat = new ArrayList<ItemChat>();
     itemsChat.add(new ItemChat(1, "Patatas", "Tuberculo", "drawable/patatas"));
     ItemChatAdapter adapter = new ItemChatAdapter(this, itemsChat);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In the layout, I have a button that´s `onClick` event is "show". It works fine, and shows my adapter defined in `ItemChat.java` class.

But, when I try the same code calling for another method, it does not work at all.

```java
public void show2 (String c){
     lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
     itemsChat = new ArrayList<ItemChat>();
     itemsChat.add(new ItemChat(1, "Patatas", c , "drawable/patatas"));
     ItemChatAdapter adapter = new ItemChatAdapter(this, itemsChat);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The difference between the two is the argument. In first, I pass View V because of the `onClick` event,
In the seccond, I try to show in the adapter `String c` instead of "Tuberculo", but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas?

PS: `onClick`  event in `show()` is from Eclipse graphic layout (Inherited from `View.onClick`)

Ok, here is my full code.

I try to implement a xmpp client, it´s work fine, Conect to gtalk server, loging usser, and received message from other user. the recieved message I can see in log, so I want to receive mje in a custom listview(something like a chat in Wahtsapp).

First  I created a custom listview and implement a button calling "Show" to test if it's work fine.

When I press Show button, my custom listview shows: a picture, Title, description and other picture. It's works perfect.

Then, I want change description in my listview instead it, put the Received message. So I use a method show(incoming message)

My main.xml file have a 2 buttons. Conectec and Show.

and listviews, id = listView

have 2 file java

ItemChat.java
ItemChatAdapter.java

and my main activity

public class MiCliente2 extends Activity {

```
private final static String SERVER_HOST = "talk.google.com";
private final static int SERVER_PORT = 5222;
private final static String SERVICE_NAME = "gmail.com"; 
private final static String LOGIN = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
private final static String PASSWORD = "xxxxxxx";
private XMPPConnection conn2;

private MessageListener messageListener;

private ArrayList<ItemChat> itemsChat;
private ListView lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mi_cliente2);

}


//when press conect button, implement this.
//it´s works perfect
public void conect (View v){
    try 
    {
         initConnection();
    Log.i("XMPPClient","Server conected");
    }
    catch(XMPPException ex){
        Log.e("XMPPClient","Error conecting to server");    
    }
}

private void initConnection() throws XMPPException {

    ConnectionConfiguration config =
    new ConnectionConfiguration(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, SERVICE_NAME);
    conn2 = new XMPPConnection(config);
    config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);

    try {
        conn2.connect();

        Log.i("XMPPClient", " Connected to " + conn2.getHost());

    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
         Log.e("XMPPClient", "Failed to connect to " + conn2.getHost());
         Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());

        }
    try {
        conn2.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + conn2.getUser());

        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        presence.setStatus("On line");
        conn2.sendPacket(presence);

        // register listeners
        ChatManager chatmanager = conn2.getChatManager();
        conn2.getChatManager().addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener()
        {
            public void chatCreated(final Chat chat, final boolean createdLocally)
            {
                chat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener()
            {
          public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message)
            {
              Log.i("XMPPClient","Received message: " 
              + (message != null ? message.getBody() : "NULL"));
        // I want to call show() passing message´s body               
              show(message.getBody());               
          }
        });
      }
    });

    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", " Failed to log in as " + LOGIN);
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
    }
}

//Not work when call show("something")
public void show(String v) {
    Log.i("XMPPClient",v); // in log can see Received message
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    itemsChat = new ArrayList<ItemChat>();            
    itemsChat.add(new ItemChat(1, "Patatas", "Tuberculo", "drawable/patatas"));

    ItemChatAdapter adapter = new ItemChatAdapter(this, itemsChat);

    Log.i("XMPPClient"," In show() before lv.setAdapter");
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //this log never happend, only can see before msje

    Log.i("XMPPClient","In show() after lvsetAdapter");
 }

//pressing "Show" button
public void show2 (View v){

     lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
     itemsChat = new ArrayList<ItemChat>();
     itemsChat.add(new ItemChat(1, "Patatas", "Tuberculo", "drawable/patatas"));
     ItemChatAdapter adapter = new ItemChatAdapter(this, itemsChat);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

When incoming message and show(meesage.getbody) not shows anything, and in logcat I see only:
 Log.i("XMPPClient"," In show() before lv.setAdapter");
not listview.

Comment: I don't see an issue in the code posted. Your problem is elsewhere. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: You say that it does not work at all. When you run `show2()`, what does display? Or does it crash? If it crashes, what error message do you get in the log?

Comment: Not crash, jut nothing hapens. I´ll put full code, maybe can helpme. I thought the prgoblem was arguments.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is "c" ? If you set it on your xml with onClick attribute, then you cannot pass any string value to this method... so what is "c" now? If you call this method from any other place, then it should work... But if you set your button's onClick attribute on your xml, then you should use it as

```
public void show(View v)
```

You may want to call your show(String c) method in your show(View c) ? Because that'll be called eventually...